# Creating a custom legend in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm hoping to have a legend that includes references to all colours, not just the vertical lines, and does not include a title.

I've tried scale_colour_manual and scale_fill_manual and they all either overlap or only show the vertical lines. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Reprex is below, including the custom colour palette.

```
var1 <- c(head(randu$x,n=12))
var2 <- as.Date(c("2010-01-01","2010-02-01","2010-03-01","2010-04-01","2010-05-01","2010-06-01","2010-07-01","2010-08-01","2010-09-01","2010-10-01","2010-11-01","2010-12-01"))
var3 <- c(tail(randu[which(randu$x + randu$y < 1),]$x,n=12))
var4 <- c(tail(randu[which(randu$x + randu$y < 1),]$y,n=12))

dat <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4)
setDT(dat)
dat$var5 <- dat[,(var3+var4)]

new_dates <- as.Date(c("2010-09-01","2010-05-01"))

cbp2 <- c("#000000", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=dat,colour=cbp2[1],fill = cbp2[1],aes(x=var2,y=var5,colour="var4"),stat="identity")+
  geom_bar(data=dat,colour=cbp2[2],fill = cbp2[2],aes(x=var2,y=var3,colour="var3"),stat="identity")+
  geom_line(data=dat,colour=cbp2[1],aes(x=var2,y=var1))+
  geom_vline(data=data.frame(xintercept = new_dates),
             aes(xintercept = new_dates,linetype = "Changes", colour="red"),
             linetype="dashed",key_glyph = "path")+
  scale_color_manual(name = "",
                     values = c("red",cbp2[2],cbp2[1]), 
                     breaks = c("red",cbp2[2],cbp2[1]),
                     labels = c("Changes","Var3","Var4"))+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",
                    values = c(cbp2[2],cbp2[1]), 
                    breaks = c(cbp2[2],cbp2[1]),
                    labels = c("var3","var4"))+
  ylab("")+
  xlab("")+
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0),date_breaks = "3 month", date_labels =  "%b %y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(var5) paste0(var5*100, "%"), 
                     limits=c(0,1),
                     breaks=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "#000000"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1),  
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x= (element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm"))),
        legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: So what exactly should be in this legend? How many groups/colors?

Comment: Four groups - two lines of black and red and two colour blocks with black and blue. They each will need to be named and the names are not all the same as the variable names.

Comment: It should be very similar to the above but with the additional variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a lot to unpack here with this one, but I gave it my best shot.

First of all, consider what you are trying to plot here.  Normally, it's not a problem to call things `var1, var2, var3,...`; however, in this context it's *really* quite confusing.  Consequently, for this solution, I will be re-posting your entire code reworked instead of just the plotting portion for reasons I hope to outline in this answer.

### The Data and the Question

With all that being said, here is my understanding about the nature of the dataset and your desire for the final plot:

- `var2` in the dataset contains `Date` class information, and this is the common `x` axis for the entire plot.
- `var1` contains values that are to be used for the `y` values of the `geom_line` plot layer
- `var3` and `var4` contain values that are to be used for creation of the *stacked barplot* which should make up the background of the plot
- `var5` is a sum of `var3 + var4`, and was a device to create the plot.  Herein, it will not be useful, given the data analysis we are to do on the dataset and the application of Tidy Data principles.
- `xintercept` Values for the `geom_vline` plot layer are supplied as the two dates `new_dates`

The OP's question indicates a need for the Legend to be displayed correctly.  In this case, we want to indicate:

- fill color of the bars as `var3` and `var4`
- the nature of the vertical lines as dashed red lines.. called "Changes"
- A label for the `geom_line` plot layer.  Assume the label will be `var1`.

Hope all that was correct!

### Synthesizing the Dataset

I encourage the OP to consult use of [Tidy Data Principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), which will make synthesis of data such as this much more straightforward in the future.  Herein, I will apply these principles to the dataset `dat`.

First of all, let's handle the **bar layer data**.  Applying Tidy Data principles, we would want to gather together `var3` and `var4` and create out of them two columns:  (1) one for the *name* of the variable (`"var3"` or `"var4"`), and (2) one for the *value*.  We will be telling `ggplot2` to "stack" bars, so `var5` is not needed here:  `ggplot2` will do that calculation automatically.  To gather the columns together, my preference is always to use `gather()` from `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

var1 <- c(head(randu$x,n=12))
var2 <- as.Date(c("2010-01-01","2010-02-01","2010-03-01","2010-04-01","2010-05-01","2010-06-01","2010-07-01","2010-08-01","2010-09-01","2010-10-01","2010-11-01","2010-12-01"))
var3 <- c(tail(randu[which(randu$x + randu$y < 1),]$x,n=12))
var4 <- c(tail(randu[which(randu$x + randu$y < 1),]$y,n=12))

dat <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4)
setDT(dat)
# dat$var5 <- dat[,(var3+var4)]   no longer needed
new_dates <- as.Date(c("2010-09-01","2010-05-01"))
cbp2 <- c("#000000", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

newdat <- dat %>% 
  gather(key='var_name', value='value', -var2) # gather all columns except for var2

names(newdat) <- c('Dates', 'var_name', 'value')
newdat$var_name <- factor(newdat$var_name, levels=c('var4', 'var3','var1'))
```

In addition to gathering together, you will also note that I'm adjusting the names of the columns to make them a bit more easier to follow when it comes down to plotting.  Additionally, I'm setting the order of the levels for `newdat$var_name`.  The purpose here is that the order we specify will relate to the ordering used to create the plot.  I want `var3` to appear as a bar "under" `var4`, so we need to specify that `var4` is first.

You could also create a separate dataset containing `var2` and `var1` to use for plotting the `geom_line` layer... but this also works fine.

### The Plot

For the plot, I've tried to organize the code into separate sections.  What OP was trying to do was to plot column-by-column, rather than using `aes(fill=` and `aes(color=` to set and create legends.  In addition, the OP's original code had numerous examples of the following:

```
geom_*(aes(color=...), color=...)
```

The result of this in `ggplot2` is that if you set an aesthetic value (like `color=`) *outside* of `aes()` while also stating this argument *inside* `aes()`, the value on the outside will overwrite the value specified inside the mapping--effectively removing any call to place that within a legend.  This was the biggest cause for issue in the OP's example, and why certain items were the "right" color, but did not appear in any legend.

Specifying arguments in `aes()` only indicates that a legend should be created and tells `ggplot2` on what basis to apply color, fill, linetype... it *does not* actually specify the color.  Color should be specified using the `scale_*_*()` functions.  In this case, we have 3 legend types created.  The OP can organize however they wish to do so, but I tried to keep this example a bit illustrative to allow for some changing on the OP's case, since it is still not entirely clear how the legend is wanted to look completely.

Note that `values=` is used to apply the color, linetype, or fill aesthetic, and is done by feeding that argument a named vector.  You can also use a non-named vector, in which case the attributes will be applied according to the ordering of the levels for that factor.

Note that I changed the line color of the `geom_line` to blue... just so that it stands out a bit.  It would be a bit confusing otherwise, since there is a fill color that is also black.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Dates, y=value)) +
  
  # plot layers
  geom_col(
    data=subset(newdat, var_name != 'var1'),
    aes(fill=var_name), position='stack') +
  geom_line(
    data=subset(newdat, var_name == 'var1'),
    aes(color=var_name)
  ) +
  geom_vline(data=data.frame(xintercept = new_dates),
                         aes(xintercept = new_dates, linetype = "Changes"), colour="red",
                         key_glyph = "path")+
 
  # color and legend settings 
  scale_fill_manual(
    name="Fill",
    values=c('var3'=cbp2[2], 'var4'=cbp2[1])) +
  
  scale_color_manual(
    name='Color',
    values = 'blue') +
  
  scale_linetype_manual(
    name='Linetype',
    values=2) +

  # scale adjustment and theme stuff
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(var5) paste0(var5*100, "%"),
                     limits=c(0,1),
                     breaks=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1)) +
  
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
                axis.line = element_line(colour = "#000000"),
                axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1),
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                axis.title.x= (element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm"))),
                legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: Your understanding was entirely correct. The legend was meant to be how you've set it up but with legend names set to blank (which can be easily done by using name= " "). Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course.  Also, my recommendation is to use `name=NULL` rather than `name=""`.  In the case of using `""`, spacing for the name is still included, whereas when it is set to `NULL`, it kind of removes it entirely.  Probably not really a difference here in a horizontal legend; however, it becomes obvious the difference this makes when you have the legends stacked on top of one another on the right or left.